# Apply Saved Filters to Custom Collection

Tags: collection, grid, filter, collection-filtering

I have created a custom grid and collection. Now, I am saving the filters to session for future use using:

```
$this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
```

and retrieving this in another controller. How am I going to apply these parameters upon loading the collection?

I can retrieve the parameters/filters using:

```
$filters = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getData('custom_block_gridfilter');
$filters = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filters);
```

Now, how am I going to apply it to?

```
Mage::getModel('custom/model')->getCollection();
```

Or perhaps how am I going to retrieve the grid collection with the filters applied to it?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection` should take care of this.

So if you have overwritten this method, maybe the problem is only, that you don't call `parent::_prepareCollection`

Comment: So this isn't possible to be retrieved using some custom model that doesn't inherit Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid?

Comment: Why would one do that?! :D And to answer the question: Sure it is doable. At least by copying all the code...

Comment: Assuming you have millions of items in a collection, then in a custom grid which has been filtered already into a smaller set, then you have another page let's say mass edit for the items that have been filtered/selected, then you might wanna retrieve those items to some other custom controller/model.